# Pushforward commutes with external tensor product?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, coherent-sheaves

Let $f:X\rightarrow X'$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Y'$ be morphisms of varieties. Let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$ and $\mathcal G$ be a coherent sheaf on $Y$. 
Is it true that

$$(f\times g)_* (\mathcal F \boxtimes \mathcal G)=
(f_* \mathcal F) \boxtimes (g_* \mathcal G)$$?

Here I used the notation 
$$\mathcal F \boxtimes \mathcal G:= \pi_X^* \mathcal F \otimes  \pi_Y^* \mathcal G $$
where the $\pi$'s stand for the projections $X \leftarrow X\times Y \rightarrow Y$.

Bonus points are awarded for an answer in the relative situation, where $f,g$ are maps of varieties flat over a base variety $B$ and $\boxtimes_B$ is defined using the projections $X \leftarrow X\times_B Y \rightarrow Y$
$$(f\times g)_* (\mathcal F \boxtimes_B \mathcal G)=
(f_* \mathcal F) \boxtimes_B (g_* \mathcal G)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $S$ be a base scheme and $f : X \to X'$ and $g : Y \to Y'$ morphisms of $S$-schemes. If $F,G \in \mathsf{Qcoh}(X),\mathsf{Qcoh}(Y)$, we have the external tensor product $F \boxtimes G \in \mathsf{Qcoh}(X \times_S Y)$. We have a canonical homomorphism (induced by the usual adjunctions)
$$f_* F \boxtimes g_* G \to (f \times g)_* (F \boxtimes G)$$
in $\mathsf{Qcoh}(X' \times_S Y')$. We ask when it is an isomorphism. Obviously, we may assume that $S$ is affine. Also, we may assume that $X'$ and $Y'$ are affine. Let us write $S=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, $X'=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, $Y'=\mathrm{Spec}(B)$. Then $A,B$ are $R$-algebras and $X$ (resp. $Y$) is an $A$-(resp. $B$-) scheme, and the homomorphism above becomes 
$$ \Gamma(X,F) \otimes_R \Gamma(Y,G) \to \Gamma(X \times_R Y,F \boxtimes G) ~~~~~ (\star)$$
in $\mathsf{Mod}(A \otimes_R B)$. The actions of $A,B$ don't matter anymore. Clearly $(\star)$ is an isomorphism when $X$ and $Y$ are affine. If $X$ is affine and $Y$ is separated and quasi-compact, then we set up the usual commutative diagram with exact columns to reduce to the affine case, *provided* that $\Gamma(X,F)$ is flat over $R$. As usual, the same proof can be used for generalizing to the case that $Y$ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated, and then also to the case that $X$ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated, provided that $\Gamma(Y,G)$ is flat.

Summary: When $f: X \to X'$ and $g : Y \to Y'$ are quasi-separated quasi-compact morphisms over some base $S$ and $F \in \mathsf{Qcoh}(X)$ is flat over $S$ and $G \in \mathsf{Qcoh}(Y)$ is flat over $S$, then
$$f_* F \boxtimes g_* G \cong (f \times g)_* (F \boxtimes G).$$

PS: I really would like to have a reference in the literature for this fact!

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick and clean answer!

Comment: Can you explain how $F$ flat over $S$ implies $\Gamma(X,F)$ flat over $R$?

Comment: Remember: $F$ is called flat over $S$ if the pushforward to $S$ is flat.

Comment: Okay this definition is not equivalent to the one in Hartshorne. For example any $F$ is flat over $S$ if its pushforward vanishes. This means also, that if we shrink $X'$ our sheaf $F$ may not stay flat? So the condition that $F,G$ are flat over $S$ won't suffice to make the above proof work?